# Sympy insert value for symbol is not working

Tags: python-3.x, sympy

I wrote a function that should calculate the Z-Transform for a given array of matrices. I use sympy to bring the z-value into the calculation. Here is the code:

```
import sympy as sy
def zTransform(mask: []) -> sy.Matrix:
z = sy.Symbol('z')
result = sy.Matrix([[0, 0], [0, 0]])
for index, matrix in enumerate(mask, start=0):
    result = result + (matrix *  z ** index)
return result
```

Regarding to the [documentation](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/matrices/matrices.html) I should be able to stub the value, but when I try to use

```
result.stubs(z,0)
```

I get the following error:

```
AttributeError: MutableDenseMatrix has no attribute stubs.
```

Why is this not working,
I use Python 3.8.2. Thanks for any help

Comment: `stubs`?  I don't find that word on the linked documentation page.

Comment: yes, because I am an idiot and this was the problem, thank you